# Validating user input in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I need to make program in Linux that will find Pictures in folder. Like JPEG, PNG, BMP. And I need to make it robbust to invalid input. Like when I write LoL instead of png it will write error.Here is my code yet:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Input what you are searching for :"
read subor

echo "-----------------------"

if [ $subor != "png" ];
then 
    echo
    echo "Nebol zadaný vstup pre PNG"
    echo
else
    Path=$ cd /home/zps/Pictures/
    command=$ find -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \; | awk '{if ($NF == "image/png") print $0}' | wc -l
fi

if [ $subor != "jpeg" ];
then 
    echo
    echo "Nebol zadaný vstup pre JPEG"
    echo
else
    Path=$ cd /home/zps/Pictures/
    command=$ find -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \; | awk '{if ($NF == "image/jpeg") print $0}' | wc -l
fi

if [ $subor != "bmp" ];
then 
    echo
    echo "Nebol zadaný vstup pre BMP" 
    echo
else
    Path=$ cd /home/zps/Pictures/
    command=$ find -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \; | awk '{if ($NF == "image/bmp") print $0}' | wc -l
fi

echo "-----------------------"
```

I tried something from internet but I just couldnt do it. I tried to make some code, and it works, I just cant figure it out how to make error when user input someting else that I want. I just need JPEG, PNG and BMP.

Comment: Remember to quote your variables!

Comment: Btw: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` statement to match all the allowed types. Then you can use a `*)` case to catch the invalid input.

```
case "$subor" in
    png) ... ;;
    jpeg) ... ;;
    bmp) ... ;;
    *) echo "Please enter png, jpeg, or bmp" ;;
esac
```